# Access - populate subform from combo box error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am very, very new to coding so please go easy!

I have followed a tutorial to allow me to populate a subform from combo boxes from the main form. I was just wondering what I can change to ensure I don't keep getting this error. When a module is added to a student I want the form to allow me to exit it if I want to or continue to not add anything else however when I try to leave the form I get an error message making me select another module. How can I stop this from happening?

Please see code and screenshots below:

[Form appearance when I have selected a student and module ready to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd6c6.png)

[Error message once I have added a module and want to leave the form, I wouldnt want students to see this or have this difficulty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSbEE.png)

Form VBA code, please note I also have the subform with LinkMaster as studentcombo and LinkChild as StudentID

```
'combo box for StudentID updates all other student detail text boxes.
Private Sub studentcombo_AfterUpdate()
    programmetb = DLookup("ProgrammeID", "tblStudent", "[StudentID]=studentcombo")
    firstnametb = DLookup("FirstName", "tblStudent", "[StudentID]=studentcombo")
    surnametb = DLookup("Surname", "tblStudent", "[StudentID]=studentcombo")
    SNtb = DLookup("StudentNumber", "tblStudent", "[StudentID]=studentcombo")
    StudentIDhidden = studentcombo
End Sub

'combo box for ModuleCode updates all other module detail text boxes.
Private Sub modulecodecombo_AfterUpdate()
    modulenametb = DLookup("ModuleName", "tblModule", "[ModuleCode]=modulecodecombo")
    creditstb = DLookup("Credits", "tblModule", "[ModuleCode]=modulecodecombo")
    semester1tb = DLookup("Semester_1", "tblModule", "[ModuleCode]=modulecodecombo")
    semester2tb = DLookup("Semester_2", "tblModule", "[ModuleCode]=modulecodecombo")
    prereqtb = DLookup("Pre_requisites", "tblModule", "[ModuleCode]=modulecodecombo")
    ModuleCodehidden = modulecodecombo
End Sub

Private Sub AddModuleBut_Click()
    'Verification that studentID is selected.
    If IsNull(studentcombo) Then
        MsgBox "Please select student", , "Required"
        studentcombo.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Verification that modulecode is selected.
    If IsNull(modulecodecombo) Then
        MsgBox "Please select a course", , "Required"
        modulecodecombo.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    'Else create a record in the subform using the combo box data.
    Else
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        StudentIDhidden = studentcombo
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the form has empty fields. Those empty required fields are not letting you exit. If you find any, then undo all data collected in the form. Put the following code in a button. Name it exit button.

```
If Me.Dirty Then
        Me.Undo
        DoCmd.Close
End If
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot! Is there a way I can code this into my add module button so that module details automatically empty when they add it?

if not this is still viable solution!

Comment: is there a way I can avoid this error altogether? If a student is selected and then you try to do anything other than select a module and add it the error will still pop-up which would look unprofessional. Can i try to avoid this altogether?

Comment: You either handle the exception or remove the required property of those fields. By choosing the latter, you will have to code more in order to verify that the data is there.